# Knockout.js Cannot check checkbox added dynamically

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on my first knockout project and I am finding that I can not check the checkboxes when they have been added to the page dynamically. I have tried the demo code from the knockout website and by it self it works fine, but my implementation does not. The result is no binding on 'checked' nor does my alert fire. The state of the boxes do not change when I click them and there are no javascript errors..

```
<div class="report">
<label>start date</label>
<input type="text" id="date-from" data-bind="value: startDate" />
<span>to </span>
<input type="text" id="date-to" data-bind="value: endDate" />
<label>product code</label>
<input type="text" id="product-code" data-bind="value: productCode" />
<label>lead type</label>
<select id="lead-type" data-bind="value: leadType">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">all</option>
    <option value="B">sales</option>
    <option value="Q">enquiries</option>
    <option value="F">failed purchases</option>
    <option value="C">cancelled purchases</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit-query" class="button" data-bind="click: load" value="Go"/>
```

Date
        Prefix
        First Name
        Last Name
        Country
        Date of Birth
        Telephone
        Email
        Global
        Complete

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var reportsViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.startDate = ko.observable();
        self.endDate = ko.observable();
        self.productCode = ko.observable();
        self.leadType = ko.observable();
        self.wantsSpam = ko.observable(true);
        self.alert = function () {
            alert(self.isActioned());
        };

        var queryData = {
            startDate: self.startDate,
            endDate: self.endDate,
            productCode: self.productCode,
            isActioned: false,
            leadType: self.leadType
        };

        function orderModel(item) {
            this.OrderDate = ko.observable(item.OrderDate),
            this.Prefix = ko.observable(item.Prefix),
            this.FirstName = ko.observable(item.FirstName),
            this.LastName = ko.observable(item.LastName),
            this.Country = ko.observable(item.Country),
            this.DateofBirth = ko.observable(item.DateofBirth),
            this.Telephone = ko.observable(item.Telephone),
            this.CustEmail = ko.observable(item.CustEmail),
            this.gbac = ko.observable(item.gbac),
            this.isActioned = ko.observable(true)
        };

        self.reportItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.load = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: sf.getServiceRoot('CC_Reporting') + "Report/getLeads",
                type: "POST",
                data: queryData,
                beforeSend: sf.setModuleHeader
            }).done(function (data, status) {
                if (data == "There are no records which match your search.") {
                    alert(data);
                    return;
                } else {
                    self.reportItems.removeAll();
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        self.reportItems.push(new orderModel(item));
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function (data) {
                alert(data);

            });
        }


    };

    ko.applyBindings(new reportsViewModel());
```

});

Comment: This is hard to test when you don't supply any sample data, but one issue is that your checkbox has an `id` in a loop, meaning it will produce invalid HTML. Also, you should move your `applyBindings` call *inside* the DOM ready function; you can't bind to elements before they exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed the id attribute but saw no change in behavior. Also, good eye about the closing..I forgot to add it in this snippet but it was in my original code

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code.

First, as I mentioned, having an `id` attribute on a DOM node in a loop is illegal.

Second, your `click` binding is inside the `foreach` binding, so its context is the `orderModel`, but the function is on the parent. Use `click: $parent.alert` to call the right function.

Third, you `alert` function is looking on `self` for the `isActioned` property, when that property is on the item. Use a parameter on your function to capture the calling context, like this:

```
self.alert = function (item) {
        alert(item.isActioned());
        return true;
    };
```

Fourth, notice the `return true`. Without that, the `click` event eats the click, stopping it from unchecking the checkbox, which you don't want to happen. returning true causes Knockout to let the event bubble.

Finally, nothing is calling `self.load()` so your ajax never fires. Here is [the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKFMG/), pared down a bit.

Comment: Thanks fro the help. I have added the html for the field and submit button. As for your example, being new to knockout the syntax is a little confusing. I still can not seem to get my example working. if i take the input and put it outside the table then the click binding works fine. it seem only when the checkboxes are dynamically added there is a problem..?

Comment: also if I move the binding click binding to the <td> holding the checkbox there is no problem, the alert come through

Comment: You have completely changed what your question content is. That HTML is nothing like what you originally posted. I am not going to help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for the help this far. The question/ issue still remains the same. My check boxes are not clickable when knockout creates them by iterating the observable array. When I say not clickable I mean the check boxes do not respond by showing or removing a check mark accordingly